# How to automatically adjust string length in the A edit descriptor?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to write a string filename in fortran using:

```
WRITE(FILENAME,'(A27,I3.3,A1,I3.3,A3)') NAME,MYPR,'_',IBL,'.nc'
```

where NAME is a string of variable lengths, and `MYPR` and `IBL` are integers. 
I'm searching for a solution where I can dynamically write the format:

```
'(A27,I3.3,A1,I3.3,A3)',
```

where `A27` will change depending on the length of `NAME`. I've tried `'A'` alone but this caused an error. I'm not sure of what is possible here as many texts do not even cover something similar issues.
Would appreciate some ideas.

Comment: *I've tried 'A' alone but this caused an error.*  What error did it cause ?  It certainly doesn't provoke either a compilation error nor a crash at run time.  I think you need to show a little more of your own code so we can spot your errors and help fix them.

Comment: I agree with @HighPerformanceMark, just using `A` instead of `A27` is working perfectly for me.

Comment: Another possibility would be to construct the format string in a (character) variable and use it instead. However, in this situation, it would be an overkill.

Comment: *I'm searching for a solution where I can dynamically write the format:*  no, you're probably not looking for that, as @AlexanderVogt has already suggested.  If you were you would (a) realise that the format string is just a string and that you can certainly write code to write it during execution; (b) but then you would discover that writing format strings during execution is a lot of bother which you could have avoided.  Answer the question I asked in my earlier comment -- what error did `A` alone cause ?

Comment: `trim(name)` with plain `a` format might be what you want.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark

The error: "forrtl: severe (61): format/variable-type mismatch, unit -5, file Internal Formatted Write" was misinterpreted by me to mean that I needed to define the length of the string, e.g., A50, instead of A, which is a point I was not sure about. Now I found that it was a type error and not format error and, from the responses, that A alone works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to use the format string `'(A,I3.3,A1,I3.3,A3)'`, i.e. using just `A` for the name and letting the compiler choose the correct length. This is working perfectly for me.

As @agentp suggested, you might see issues due to whitespaces in the string. This might be resolved by using `trim(name)` to get rid of trailing whitespace, or even `trim(adjustl(name))` which removes both leading and trailing whitespace. This solution is given below in subroutine `print1()`.

The other option would be to generate the format string dynamically - after all, that is just a string as well. This is quite cumbersome, and an overkill in your situation - see `print2()`.

```
module test_mod
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine print1(NAME,MYPR,IBL)
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: NAME
    integer,intent(in)          :: MYPR,IBL

    WRITE(*,'(A,I3.3,A1,I3.3,A3)') trim(adjustl(NAME)),MYPR,'_',IBL,'.nc'
  end subroutine

  subroutine print2(NAME,MYPR,IBL)
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: NAME
    integer,intent(in)          :: MYPR,IBL

    character(len=128)          :: fmt

    write(fmt,*) len_trim(adjustl(NAME))
    fmt = '(A'//trim(adjustl(fmt))//',I3.3,A1,I3.3,A3)'
    WRITE(*,fmt) trim(adjustl(NAME)),MYPR,'_',IBL,'.nc'
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use test_mod
  call print1(' Testfile   ', 1, 2)
  call print2(' Testfile   ', 1, 2)
end program
```

Output:

```
./a.out 
Testfile001_002.nc
Testfile001_002.nc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm work a lot in fortran but not much in more complicated I/O. Thanks for example, editing of the text, and for the overall edification :-)